# Copying the Linkage of Google Sheets and Google Slides

Tags: google-chrome, google-sheets, google-slides

I have a Google Slide where all the charts are generated via a linked Google Sheet. I am trying to find a way of duplicating this Original Slide/Sheet to a new 'instance' - whereby the new 'instance' allows me to independently edit the New Google Sheet and it update the New Google Slide.

I tried to edit the linked object source within the New Slide but this does not seem to be possible. I cannot find a way to edit the New Google Slide and link charts to a different spreadsheet
edit the individual charts and link them to a new spreadsheet/data source.

I have also tried copying both files (Slide + Sheet), placing both files in a folder and duplicating the entire folder. However the Slide in the 'Copy' simply links to the original Sheet.

Currently, it looks like I have to delete all the charts in the New (duplicated) Slide and then re-add them by inserting new charts. This would be very time consuming - not only do they have to be re-added, but they need to be re-sized, re-positioned and the order re-arranged (so we can easily edit certain text/graphics that sit above them).

Comment: If you change the data on the Spreadsheet and then go to the duplicate slide and update the chart (** and you do not update the original slide**) you will end up with two slides with two different charts. If you want to keep the information of the Spreadsheet you could copy/paste it to another sheet every time you need to add the next chart. [Here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7009814?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) is more information about this. **Is this what you were looking for?** Thanks !